# WCF services on 64 bit and 32 bit machine

Tags: wcf, 32bit-64bit

we created WCF services which is having high traffic consumption.multiple clients make request to services per second to get live data from server.

when I deployed services on UAT on below configuration machine then IIS 7.5 consumes cpu process around 30-35%.

machine configuration -
windows 7 professinal
Intel(R)Core(TM)i3-2120 CPU@3.30GHz
RAM - 4 GB
32 bit operating system

When I deployed services on IIS 7.5 on below configuration machine then IIS consumes around 60-70% of cpu process.
Machine Configuration -
Windows server 2008 R2 standard
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5649 @2.53 GHz 2.53 GHz (2 processor)
RAM-6GB
64 bit operating system

I do not understand why on high configuration server with 64 bit machine,same code consumes more cpu processes. Please suggest on this.
Thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 0):

Is you're IIS 7.5 application pool is running in 32-bit compatibility mode or not. Try to switch. But I don't think the problem is comming from 32bit or 64bit OS.